# ¿Cómo usar String.concat() para dar un valor con símbolo $? NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, string, concat

Debo retornar el monto que cada comensal debe pagar (total divido entre 5), con símbolo `$` adelante, y debo usar el método `concat` de `String` para imprimir con el símbolo `$` adelante.

```
module.exports = function restaurantAzul(azul=50) {
    // 1. Crea una variable llamada tax y asígnale el resultado de multiplicar azul por %10
    var tax = azul*0.10;

    // 2. Crea una variable llamada total y asígnale el resultado de sumar azul más tax
    var total = azul+tax

    // 3. Retorna el monto que cada conensal debe pagar, con el símbolo $ adelante
    return control.log();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de dos maneras, la primera es usando la función **`concat()`** y la otra con un simple **`+`**.

```js
var currency = "$";
var value = 10.5;

// Utilizando la función concat sobre el string
console.log(currency.concat(value));
// ==> $10.5

// Utilizando +
console.log(currency + value);
// ==> $10.5
```

Yo te aconsejo utilizar la función **`concat()`**, asegurándote que el tipo de variable *`currency`* sea de tipo string.